# Do we have to worry about liquid leveler being too heavy?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, leveling

We're having flooring installed soon and our current floors have a decent slope to them and aren't level. The installer is going to use a liquid leveler. Do we have to worry about it being too heavy if it's used over the entire floor, especially when some spots are an inch (or more) higher than others?

Edit: The initial floor installer said liquid leveler would be too heavy. They got busy and we had another installer assigned to us. This second installer said liquid leveler is just fine and not too heavy.

Comment: Why is the floor so uneven???  Is it structurally sound?

Comment: Is the existing floor wood or concrete?

Comment: An inch is a large amount and will need to be done with several pours , is it two heavy? Probably not as long is the structure is sound, on a wood structure I would be attempting to level the floors by jacking (unless it was originally a sloped deck that the walls were built on top of.

Comment: It's a house on the river, built in 1970, that has had additions to it. The existing floor is wood.

Comment: Never tried such a thing, but my first thought with an inch is to add plywood in various sections to get the level everywhere closer to where it should be. For example, starting where it is ~ 3/8" below, add 3/8" plywood until it gets ~ 1/2" below and there use 1/2" plywood etc. That would get everything within ~ 3/8" (or perhaps 1/2" except perhaps for some gaps around edges, etc. Additional work but the actual leveler needed would be cut in 1/2. That only works if it is all sloped in one direction. And my idea may be too crazy to work which is why it is just a comment.